# Macbook Pro cannot connect to Wireless Hotspot created by a Ubuntu 12.04 Laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, unix, tethering

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my dell laptop and have created a wi-fi hotspot, with WEP 40/128bit encryption (And I know the security key).

My Macbook Pro finds this network but when I try to connect I get a dialog saying "This network uses WPA enterprise authentication" and asks me for username and password.

None of the following combinations for username and password worked:

Username : network name
Password: network key

Username: my ubuntu system username
Username: my ubuntu system password

I tried setting the hotspot in both Ad-hoc and Infrastructure mode. Neither worked.

Notes :

1) I am very new to Mac world.
2) I access internet via a 4G (LTE) USB Modem. Hence the need to setup Wi-Fi hotspot.

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you actually know the WEP? or just guessing it !

Comment: @Buscar웃 If you are asking whether I know the WEP key, then yes I do. I am setting up the hotspot and I know the security key. Edited the question to reflect it.

Comment: Does it connects if you do not use WPA?